# Is it possible to implement virtual network based on MAC in IP instead of MAC in UDP?

Tags: vlan, ip, protocol-theory, transport-protocol, tunnel

We know that flannel use `MAC in UDP` to create a overlay network. My question is:

UDP header only provides an extra port number fields, let's suppose that 
 one physical machine only run one `flanneld` process, so there is no need to distinguish which process to forward the packet by port number. In this case, can we left out the UDP layer and only put the Layer2 data in an IP frame?

Another way to ask this question is:
`Does port number important when building a virtual network`

I know this idea seems crazy, but I only want to discuss whether it is possible.

Also, we can imagine that a new protocol type number is given, and flannel can have some part running as a kernel module.

Comment: I guess the short answer is, Yes it's possible, but why go through all the effort to register a new protocol, when MAC over UDP is so easy to implement?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The IPv4 packet header has a protocol field, and the IPv6 packet header has the Next Header field. Both of those perform the same function. The value of the field will be a registered protocol to which the payload of the IP packet will be passed.

IANA maintains the list of registered protocol numbers at *[Protocol Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml)*. If your protocol has a registered protocol number and a handler registered with IP, then IP will pass the packet payload to the protocol handler.

How your, currently non-existent, protocol operates is something that we cannot answer for you because it doesn't actually exist, and the vendor of Flannel does not offer optional, paid support, so it is off-topic here, as are questions about your host/server OS.

---

For example, OSPF has the registered protocol number of `89`. If there is an OSPF process in the host that has registered to IP, then any IP packets with `89` in the protocol field will be passed to the OSPF process. In essence OSPF has its own transport protocol, not relying on the common TCP or UDP transport protocols.